# DataTables Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1 FeathersJs

Tags: mongodb, datatables, datatables-1.10, feathersjs

I have featherjs app and trying to use datatables. I am using ajax datasource with configuration below:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
          "url": "<url-placeholder>",
          "dataType": "json",
          "cache": true,  // this is to remove the '_' sent by datatables
          "data": function(params) {
            // Put additional parameters here
            return params;
          },
          "dataSrc": function(result) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(result.data);
            console.log(data);

            return data;
          },
          "columns": [
            { data: "_id" },
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "symbol" }
          ]
      }
    });
```

I have HTML like this

```
<table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

The server returned this:

> [{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce2c","name":"ABS-CBN","symbol":"ABS"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce2d","name":"AC PREF B2","symbol":"ACPB2"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce2e","name":"Asiabest Gorup","symbol":"ABG"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce2f","name":"AC PREF B1","symbol":"ACPB1"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce30","name":"Anchor Land","symbol":"ALHI"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce31","name":"Bogo Medellin","symbol":"BMM"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce32","name":"DAVINCI CAPITAL","symbol":"DAVIN"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce33","name":"FIRST METRO ETF","symbol":"FMETF"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce34","name":"IPeople","symbol":"IPO"},{"_id":"5abdd8548d46ed03dcb0ce35","name":"Manila Bulletin","symbol":"MB"}]

The datatables returning this error. And I have searched for answers for many hours now. I am stuck on this error

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: Error is for null columns in array. Data posted looks ok, can you please check all fields are present if there are more rows?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya - in dataSrc I logged the result.data and return it in a function. I checked there's no extra data on it. Of course the result object contains other properties but I just grab the result.data/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you have the `columns` definition within the Ajax block - it should be outside:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<url-placeholder>",
        "dataType": "json",
        "cache": true, // this is to remove the '_' sent by datatables
        "data": function(params) {
            // Put additional parameters here
            return params;
        },
        "dataSrc": function(result) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(result.data);
            console.log(data);

            return data;
        }
    },

    "columns": [
        { data: "_id" },
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "symbol" }
      ]

});
```

I don't believe that the `cache` and `dataType` options are supported by DataTables, but try removing those after moving the `columns` block first.

Comment: the 'columns' property is outside the ajax property. the closing curly brace is for the dataTables option declaration

Comment: No, sorry, with your nesting in the original code you pasted, the columns declaration is definitely within the Ajax block! I just double and triple checked to be sure :)